# A geometrical interpretation of the product of a positive diagonal matrix and a matrix with positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to shed some light on a recurrent problem I find while studying control systems. In many of the systems I work with, their stability depends on the eigenvalues of a matrix $B = U^{-1}A$, where $U_{ii} = u + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}|A_{ij}|, u \geq 0$, with $A,U,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. These can also be regarded as the solutions $\lambda$ of the GEP $Av = \lambda Uv$.

Particularly, the systems I study "work properly" (i.e., they are stable) when the eigenvalues of $B$ are positive. I know that this happens for sure if $A$ is symmetric and has positive eigenvalues since $U$ is positive-definite by definition. On the other hand, removing the symmetry condition on $A$ renders the positivity of its eigenvalues insufficient for the same conclusion.

What I wanted to understand, is if there is a "geometrical" approach that can give some insight into why symmetry is so important in this case, and tie this approach with the more formulaic one. I know that a matrix can be eigen-decomposed as $A = VDV^{-1}$, and that for symmetric matrices the eigenvectors are orthogonal, so $V^{-1} = V^T$ or in other words $V$ is a rotation. Is there a way to "visualize" the difference (in terms of the composition of $V^{-1}$ transformation - $D$ scaling - $V$ transformation - ...) between $A\cdot[e_1 e_2]$ and $U^{-1}A \cdot[e_1 e_2]$ in the following cases:

1. $A$ symmetric with positive eigenvalues
2. $A$ nonsymmetric with positive eigenvalues and $U^{-1}A$ with positive eigenvalues
3. $A$ nonsymmetric with positive eigenvalues and $U^{-1}A$ with negative eigenvalues
4. $A$ with positive and negative eigenvalues

that explains the "geometric significance" of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the composition $U^{-1}A$ in terms of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $U,A$, or on any other suitable set of vectors?

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $U^{-1}A$ is similar to $U^{-1/2}AU^{-1/2}$. If $A$ is symmetric, then this second matrix is also symmetric

Comment: Yes, it is true, and that can be used to show why if $A$ is symmetric PD, then also $U^{-1}A$ has positive eigenvalues (since it will be similar to the matrix you proposed, which has strictly positive eigenvalues and is symmetric and hence is PD). However, I still fail to see what is the "geometric" difference (if applicable – I find it easy to visualize geometry, but there may be no appreciable characteristics that allow to point out vastly differing behaviors in the cases specified) between this case, and the one where $A$ is not symmetric.